# Edit the specific element in the clicked row using index

Tags: angular, typescript

Target a specific row for edit functionality using the row index. When I tried to click on the edit button for specific row, the event is traverse to all the rows.

When I tried to click on the edit button for specific row, the event is traverse to all the rows.

#### home.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records; let i = index">
   <td>
      <span *ngIf="!enableEdit">{{record.userId}}</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="record.userId" *ngIf="enableEdit"/>
   </td>
   <td>
      <span *ngIf="!enableEdit">{{record.id}}</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.id" *ngIf="enableEdit"/>
   </td>
   <td>
      <span *ngIf="!enableEdit">{{record.title}}</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.title" *ngIf="enableEdit"/>
   </td>
   <td>
      <span *ngIf="!enableEdit">{{record.body}}</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.body" *ngIf="enableEdit"/>
   </td>
   <td><button type="button" (click)="editColumn(record, $event);">Edit</button></td>
   <td><button type="button" (click)="updateColumn(record, i)">Update</button></td>
</tr>
```

#### home.component.ts

```
editColumn(record: any, event: Event) 

{
    console.log('edit row data', record);

    this.enableEdit =!this.enableEdit;

`enter code here`}
```

How can I achieve the edit for specific row using index?

Comment: You are using **one** single variable `enableEdit`, so it will become `true` or `false` for all rows. You need unique values for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable in the .ts file called *editingIndex*. Then update the code to check if the *editingIndex === i* instead of using *enableEdit*

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records; let i = index">
   <td>
      <span *ngIf="editingIndex !== i">{{record.userId}}</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="record.userId" *ngIf="editingIndex === i"/>
   </td>
   ...
   <td><button type="button" (click)="editColumn(record, i);">Edit</button></td>
   <td><button type="button" (click)="updateColumn(record, i)">Update</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then editColumn code in the .ts file will set the "editingIndex" variable.

```
let editingIndex;
...
editColumn(record: any, index: number) 

{
    console.log('edit row data', record);

    this.editingIndex = index;

`enter code here`}
```

Comment: I agree with using the index, but you don't need to pass in the full element as the first arg. You can just pass in the index and `records[i]` since you already have the array in the component.